# squarespace: send form data to email without using php

Tags: php, forms, email, squarespace

I am using an html form in a website hosted by squarespace. after the form is submitted, I want to send the form data in an email.
to my understanding, squarespace currently does not support php implementation, so I cant use a php script.
note that I also cant use the built in forms in squarespace (even though they have the option to send an email with the data).
what else can I use to send the data to an email? any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Read this: http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-email-form.phtml

Comment: thank you.  will javascript always display a warning to the user before sending the email?